# iOS to display a headline and a paragraph

Tags: ios

I want to compose a view in an ios app that includes a headline and a paragraph. It will look a lot like an HTML page with h1 tag and p tag, how do I make them look like that in iOS? What controls should I use? I would prefer the answer to work with UI Builder instead of dynamical objects in code.

What I tried is using labels, and it didn't work well.

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't labels work?  I would recommend subclassing UIView to hold two labels (heading and paragraph) and style them appropriately.  You'll need to specify what your issues with the labels were and what exactly you're trying to accomplish if you need further advice.

Comment: label seem to be fixed height once I set the height in UI builder. I want something that would expand as needed. And the headline sometimes gets long (I size the label to be one-line), and it just resize the text for me automatically, I don't want it to be resized, I want it to be extend to another line if it's too long.

Answer (score 1):

The long-standing approach for doing this is with multiple labels (UILabel), each in a different style/font/color. This is not difficult, but with multiline labels iOS will try to center the text vertically for you, so you have to lay out the height of the labels in code, using `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`, and then you have to position the labels correctly in code.

I must stress that this is not hard to do. It is tedious but it works.

However, in iOS 6, the problem is completely solved: you can just use NSAttributedString. This lets you create *one* string consisting of multiple paragraphs in different styles/fonts/colors, which is a way doing for real the very thing we were trying to simulate earlier using multiple UILabel objects. You get to dictate margins, spacing between paragraphs, etc. - the whole works. It's fantastic.

I suggest you watch the WWDC 2012 videos concerning attributed strings in iOS 6. Do not, however, believe their repeated mantra that UILabel is your locus of power for displaying attributed strings. I have found, for example, in rewriting my app, that multiparagraph attributed strings do not always play nicely with UILabel. So I have found it easiest to lay out the attributed string by drawing it directly in the `drawRect:` of a custom view, using the new NSAttributedString `drawWithRect:options:context:` method.